# How to add the Certificate in SSL conncetions (Hubconncection) in SignalR

Tags: android, ssl, connection, signalr, ssl-certificate

I want to add the certificate to the connection I made in connecting to signal R but I don't know how to add the certificate to Hubconnection object.
This is my code that I use to make a signal E connection using Hubconnection.

```
 Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

    String serverUrl = "https://......................."; 
    temp=new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl,"AccessToken="+Reply.getAccessToken(),true,temp.getLogger());
    String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "ChatHub";
    mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);
    mHubConnection.getConnectionData();
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());

    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);
    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e("SimpleSignalR", e.toString());
        return;
    }


    String CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE = "SignOutUser";
    mHubProxy.on(CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
            new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void run(String msg) {
                    final String finalMsg =  msg.toString();
                    // display Toast message
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            MainActivity.serverLogout(finalMsg);
                        }
                    });
                }


            }
            , String.class);
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`Certificates`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/b73cbabe69bc48c4cb8d768148e157712a264ce9/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/Connection.cs#L278) property?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to, please explain more. I have a certificate successfully when using **web socket** class or **okhttp** class but with **hubconnection** class I can't add this property (**certificate**).

Comment: I pointed to a class HubConnection derives from. You may need to cast to your hubConnection to IConnection because it is an explicit interface implementation. Also, I think you need to use the latest version (2.2.2) of the client that targets netstandard (the API is #ifdef'd out for non-.NET Framewok, non-netstandard versions of the client)

Comment: I'm new to use **SignalR** or Connections at all so I don't know what you are meaning so if you can give me some **code snippets** to look at, I am search for code for client side not **server** side and also when I checked **Hubconnection** class and its parent class in android I couldn't find any parameter that I can use as a **connection** parameter like **okhttp** that I can add a certificate parameter to.